# r conditional subtract number

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subtraction

I am trying to do the following logic to create 'subtract' column.
I have years from 1986-2014 and around 100 firms.

```
year  firm   count sum_of_year  subtract
1986   A       1       2           2
1986   B       1       2           4
1987   A       2       4           5
1987   C       1       4           2
1987   D       1       4           5
1988   C       3       5
1988   E       2       5
```

That is, if a firm *i* at *t* appears in *t+1*, then subtract its count at *t+1* from the sum_of_year at *t+1*,

if a firm *i* does not appear in *t+1*, then just put sum_of_year at *t+1* as shown in the sample.

I am having difficulties in creating this conditional code.

How can I do this in a generalized version?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: How is `subtract` 4 for second row when there is only one row for `B` ? Can you explain the calculation ?

Comment: Hi, B in 1986 did not appear in 1987, so its subtract value equals 4, sum_of_year in 1987 - 0, count of B in 1987.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `dplyr` with the help of `tidyr::complete`. We complete the missing combinations of rows for `year` and `firm` and `fill` `count` with 0. For each `year`, we subtract the `count` by `sum` of `count` for that entire `year` and finally for each `firm`, we take the value from the next year using `lead`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  tidyr::complete(year, firm, fill = list(count = 0)) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  mutate(n = sum(count) - count) %>%
  group_by(firm) %>%
  mutate(subtract = lead(n)) %>%
  filter(count != 0) %>%
  select(-n)


#   year firm  count sum_of_year subtract
#  <int> <fct> <dbl>       <int>    <dbl>
#1  1986 A         1           2        2
#2  1986 B         1           2        4
#3  1987 A         2           4        5
#4  1987 C         1           4        2
#5  1987 D         1           4        5
#6  1988 C         3           5       NA
#7  1988 E         2           5       NA
```